# How to interact with Java from Python

Tags: java, python, api, matlab, jython

I currently use Matlab as a scientific computing language, but am interested in moving to a more open alternative.  Python (+scipy +numpy +matplotlib) seems like the best way to go.  My biggest worry about the switch is that Python won't interact as nicely/easily/seamlessly with Java as Matlab does and I often need to use Java APIs.  In particular I like that in Matlab:

1) I can instantiate Java objects and access their member variables and methods

2) Java events become "Callbacks" in Matlab

3) Java types get automatically cast to Matlab types (boolean to logical, etc)

As far as I can tell there are 3 options in Python (below).  My worry is that each is supported/developed by a very small community of developers (1-3 people in each case as I understand) and that support may not be there forever.  Which of the below does the two things Matlab does?  Which is most likely to continue to do that for the foreseeable future?  It would be a bonus if I could use Java GUIs from Python as well.  Did I miss any options?

1) Jython

2) Py4J

3) JPype

Comment: As far as I know Jython supports these requirements, but I don't have so much experience in the topic.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to do that? Is it because you have legacy library code written in java? In the long term it would probably be better to have all your code in python(or C with which it interfaces very well) rather than a python/java mix. Having used matlab I understand why you'd want to call into non-matlab code for some tasks(given that matlab is horrendous for general purpose programming) but you won't have that problem if you're using python

Comment: PS: Jython won't work. Check this faq answer: http://scipy.github.com/faq.html#id23 In general, programs written in Jython won't have access to C-extensions written for CPython. Given that most(if not all) scientific libraries for python have their core functionality written in C, well, that won't work out so well

Comment: Thanks, nor do I clearly.  I guess my problem with Jython is that it seems like it'll always be a step behind Python and not necessarily fully compatible.  Is that a legitimate concern?

Comment: It is b/c there are Java APIs that I want to use (and some associated legacy code).

Comment: Seems Jython is definitely not going to work: [does numpy/scipy work with jython](http://scipy.github.com/faq.html#does-numpy-scipy-work-with-jython)

Comment: Here's quite a good overview with source code examples which shows the dis-/advantage and usage of each technology: https://talvi.net/a-brief-overview-of-python-java-bridges-in-2020.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this since SciPy and friends don't currently run on Jython.  You could run things as client-server or as a subprocess with redirected standard input/output/error.

I've also toyed with XML-RPC in one of my Python projects, I've got a [blurb from the docs](http://nditoolbox.chriscoughlin.com/plugins_samples.html#dev_sample_java) available that might be helpful.  You won't get the best performance in the world going this route but it does have the virtue of being fairly easy to get started.